# Expo build is failing due to error that is currently working in my codebase when I run my app for testing

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I have a react application that I am working on. I finished it and now I want to build it and deploy it to the app store throuhg expo. The issue is that when I go to build it with the code `eas build --platform ios`. It starts building and then i keep running into the same error that breaks the build. When i run the application and make sure that there is not issue with the code. It all runs correctly. I have no idea why it is breaking my build.

This is the build code log:

```
Creating Gymfile
Gymfile created
Successfully loaded '/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/ios/Gymfile' 
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  Detected Values from './Gymfile'                                                                   |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| suppress_xcode_output | true                                                                                                                                        |
| clean                 | false                                                                                                                                       |
| scheme                | Reipp                                                                                                                                       |
| configuration         | Release                                                                                                                                     |
| export_options        |                                                                                                                                             |
| export_xcargs         | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/turtle-v2-325ee6f1-7430-4748-9596-72fa4e6c97eb.keychain" |
| disable_xcpretty      | true                                                                                                                                        |
| buildlog_path         | /Users/expo/workingdir/logs                                                                                                                 |
| output_directory      | ./build                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./Reipp.xcworkspace -scheme Reipp -configuration Release
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:03.057 xcodebuild[4079:11434] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:03.058 xcodebuild[4079:11434] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

[stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB03CB85-009E-4017-8EBE-14EC01AE8FD2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
[stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A147CC3C-E896-4D76-9012-878356117872, OS:15.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.reipp.app"=>"4371396b-94ba-4104-abe9-ae092e530330"}
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                     Summary for gym 2.206.1                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| workspace                                         | ./Reipp.xcworkspace                                                                                                                         |
| scheme                                            | Reipp                                                                                                                                       |
| clean                                             | false                                                                                                                                       |
| output_directory                                  | ./build                                                                                                                                     |
| output_name                                       | Reipp                                                                                                                                       |
| configuration                                     | Release                                                                                                                                     |
| silent                                            | false                                                                                                                                       |
| skip_package_ipa                                  | false                                                                                                                                       |
| skip_package_pkg                                  | false                                                                                                                                       |
| export_options.method                             | app-store                                                                                                                                   |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.reipp.app | 4371396b-94ba-4104-abe9-ae092e530330                                                                                                        |
| export_xcargs                                     | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/turtle-v2-325ee6f1-7430-4748-9596-72fa4e6c97eb.keychain" |
| build_path                                        | /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-09-26                                                                                     |
| result_bundle                                     | false                                                                                                                                       |
| buildlog_path                                     | /Users/expo/workingdir/logs                                                                                                                 |
| destination                                       | generic/platform=iOS                                                                                                                        |
| suppress_xcode_output                             | true                                                                                                                                        |
| xcodebuild_formatter                              | xcpretty                                                                                                                                    |
| disable_xcpretty                                  | true                                                                                                                                        |
| skip_profile_detection                            | false                                                                                                                                       |
| xcodebuild_command                                | xcodebuild                                                                                                                                  |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution              | false                                                                                                                                       |
| disable_package_automatic_updates                 | false                                                                                                                                       |
| use_system_scm                                    | false                                                                                                                                       |
| xcode_path                                        | /Applications/Xcode.app                                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
$ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./Reipp.xcworkspace -scheme Reipp -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-09-26/Reipp\ 2022-09-26\ 22.53.11.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/expo/workingdir/logs/Reipp-Reipp.log > /dev/null
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:12.081 xcodebuild[4133:11735] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:12.082 xcodebuild[4133:11735] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
▸ 2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » Yoga.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » vlog_is_on.cc
› Packaging expo Pods/Expo » libExpo.a
› Compiling expo-font Pods/EXFont » EXFontLoader.m
› Compiling expo-font Pods/EXFont » EXFont.m
› Compiling expo-font Pods/EXFont » EXFont-dummy.m
› Executing expo-file-system Pods/EXFileSystem » [CP] Copy XCFrameworks
› Compiling expo-keep-awake Pods/ExpoKeepAwake » ExpoKeepAwake-dummy.m
› Packaging expo-font Pods/EXFont » libEXFont.a
› Compiling expo-error-recovery Pods/EXErrorRecovery » EXErrorRecoveryModule.m
› Compiling expo-error-recovery Pods/EXErrorRecovery » EXErrorRecovery-dummy.m
› Packaging expo-keep-awake Pods/ExpoKeepAwake » libExpoKeepAwake.a
› Executing expo-keep-awake Pods/ExpoKeepAwake » Copy generated compatibility header
› Executing expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » [CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest
› Compiling expo-application Pods/EXApplication » EXProvisioningProfile.m
› Compiling expo-application Pods/EXApplication » EXApplication.m
› Packaging expo-error-recovery Pods/EXErrorRecovery » libEXErrorRecovery.a
› Compiling expo-application Pods/EXApplication » EXApplication-dummy.m
› Packaging expo-application Pods/EXApplication » libEXApplication.a
› Compiling expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » EXConstantsService.m
› Compiling expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » EXConstantsInstallationIdProvider.m
› Compiling EXConstants-dummy.m
› Packaging expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » libEXConstants.a
› Compiling Pods/Pods-Reipp » Pods-Reipp-dummy.m
› Packaging Pods/Pods-Reipp » libPods-Reipp.a
› Executing Reipp » [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock
› Executing Reipp » Start Packager on http://localhost:8081
› Compiling Reipp » ExpoModulesProvider.swift
› Compiling Reipp » noop-file.swift
› Compiling Reipp » main.m
› Compiling Reipp » AppDelegate.mm
› Compiling Reipp » Reipp_vers.c
› Linking   Reipp » Reipp
› Copying   ios/Reipp/Supporting/Expo.plist ➜ ./Expo.plist
› Compiling Reipp » SplashScreen.storyboard
› Preparing Reipp » Info.plist
› Generating debug Reipp » Reipp.app.dSYM
› Executing Reipp » Bundle React Native code and images
    the transform cache was reset.
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reipp-gorbnnjknomygnfxwixidlmwggov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Reipp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Reipp.build/Release-iphoneos/Reipp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Reipp' from project 'Reipp')
▸ (1 failure)
2022-09-26 22:53:12.081 xcodebuild[4133:11735] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-09-26 22:53:12.082 xcodebuild[4133:11735] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
2022-09-26 22:53:12.142 xcodebuild[4133:11735] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reipp-gorbnnjknomygnfxwixidlmwggov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Reipp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Reipp.build/Release-iphoneos/Reipp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Reipp' from project 'Reipp')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           Build environment           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version | 2.206.1                 |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS15.5.sdk        |
+-------------+-------------------------+
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
sure your project is set up correctly.
fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[stderr] [!] Error building the application - see the log above
error Unable to resolve module ../../zillow from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/src/screens/ContactAgentScreen.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * zillow(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * zillow/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  4 | import axios from 'axios'
  5 |
> 6 | import { extendedPropertOptions, singlePropertyOptions } from '../../zillow'
    |                                                                ^
  7 |
  8 | import PropertySampleComponent from '../components/GeneralComponents/PropertySampleComponent'
  9 | import ContactAgentComponent from '../components/PropertyScreenComponents.js/ContactAgentComponent'.
Error: Unable to resolve module ../../zillow from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/src/screens/ContactAgentScreen.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * zillow(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * zillow/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  4 | import axios from 'axios'
  5 |
> 6 | import { extendedPropertOptions, singlePropertyOptions } from '../../zillow'
    |                                                                ^
  7 |
  8 | import PropertySampleComponent from '../components/GeneralComponents/PropertySampleComponent'
  9 | import ContactAgentComponent from '../components/PropertyScreenComponents.js/ContactAgentComponent'
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
info 
Error: Fastlane build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases for more information.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when looking for an error message.
```

Here is the object code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'
import axios from 'axios'

import { extendedPropertOptions, singlePropertyOptions } from '../../zillow'

import PropertySampleComponent from '../components/GeneralComponents/PropertySampleComponent'
import ContactAgentComponent from '../components/PropertyScreenComponents.js/ContactAgentComponent'


const ContactAgentScreen = ({route}) => {

  console.log(extendedPropertOptions)
  console.log(singlePropertyOptions)

  const [addressLookup, setAddressLookup] = useState('')
  const [currentHome, setCurrentHome] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    if(route.params?.zpid){
      getPropertyDetails(route.params.zpid)
    }
  }, [])

  const newSearch = () => {
    extendedPropertOptions.params.location = addressLookup
    axios.request(extendedPropertOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        Object.keys(response.data).length == 1 ? getPropertyDetails(response.data.zpid) : console.log('no detail found')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  const getPropertyDetails = (zpid) => {
    singlePropertyOptions.params.zpid = zpid
    axios.request(singlePropertyOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        setCurrentHome(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Connect With An Agent</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Feather style={styles.chevronDown} size={20} name='search'/>
        <TextInput 
          value={addressLookup}
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={setAddressLookup}
          placeholder={'Enter an address'}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.searcingContainer} onPress={() => {newSearch()}}>
          <Text style={styles.searchSubmit}>Search</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {
        Object.keys(currentHome).length == 0 ? null : <View style={styles.property}><PropertySampleComponent item={currentHome}/></View>
      }
      <ContactAgentComponent currentHome={currentHome}/>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 44
  },
  row: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 46,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  header: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 56,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
  },
  chevronDown: {
    color: '#1c39bb',
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 6
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    marginLeft: 16
  },
  input: {
    width: '70%',
    fontSize: 17,
    paddingTop: 4,
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 2
  },
  searcingContainer: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  searchSubmit: {
    fontSize: 17,
    color: '#273be2'
  },
  property: {
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
})

export default ContactAgentScreen
```

I have no idea why it is breaking. I even ran the `console.log()` and they both displayed the correct information that I am expecting to see.

This is an image of my file strucutre:

[image: file structure]

This is an image of the build page:

[image: build page]

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue today as well with eas build --platform ios --local, I did just update to XCode Version 14.0.1 (14A400), maybe that caused this issue:

`[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** [RUN_FASTLANE] ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** [RUN_FASTLANE] Exit status: 65`

Comment: Same, I've also updated Xcode. Never update Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

After updating XCode I also run into issues.

Following this helped me:

> Add this `post_install` section to your `Podfile`:
>
> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>         config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
>         config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
>         config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
>        end
>     end
>   end
> ```

more: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1806